# I have an issue with geofences Transition Exit.I am working on getting an notification when he entered and exit the location

Tags: android

I am working on notification when i enter the location that mentioned in Constants.java.the problem is...i used fakelocation app and kept some far location but still getting notification like entered and when exit ..also getting entered notification...

My complete code:
    enter code here
    Constants.java:

```
public class Constants {

public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 1000;





  public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String,          LatLng>();



 static {
        // Shoppers Stop
        LANDMARKS.put("Shoppers Stop", new LatLng(17.729192, 83.314607));

        // aucampus
        LANDMARKS.put("aucampus", new LatLng(17.729020, 83.320096));

        //my home
        LANDMARKS.put("Krishna temple",new LatLng(17.735146, 83.327637));
        //central
        LANDMARKS.put("cmr central",new LatLng(17.734472, 83.318418));

        LANDMARKS.put("Spencers",new LatLng(17.730323, 83.314254));
    }
}

MAinActivity.java





public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<Status> {

    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;


    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mAddGeofencesButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Button mAddGeofencesButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);


        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();


        populateGeofenceList();

        // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    private void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();

   new GeofenceTransitionsIntentService().onHandleIntent(getIntent());
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences  not Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        }

    }
//for adding geofences //
    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google API Client not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
//        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }
}

GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java

public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";


    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {

        super(TAG);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (event.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + event.getErrorCode());
            return;

        }
        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition1 = event.getGeofenceTransition();



        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition1 == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition1 == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT||geofenceTransition1==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {


            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = event.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition1,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);

            String geofenceTransition =getTransitionString(geofenceTransition1);
            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransition);
//            String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
//            sendNotification(description);
        }
       // getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String geofenceTransition) {

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
//        }

            // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            }
            // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
            }

            // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
            PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                    null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=        android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }

            // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            // Define the notification settings.
            builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.color.background_dark)
                    // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                    // to decode the Bitmap.
                    .setColor(Color.RED)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification")
                    .setContentText(geofenceTransition.toString())
                    .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

            // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);

            // Get an instance of the Notification manager
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Issue the notification
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

        }
    }

 private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService geofenceTransitionsIntentService, int geofenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);
        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    public String getTransitionString(int geofenceTransition) {
        switch (geofenceTransition) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return "entered";
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return "exited";
            default:
                return "happyy";
        }
    }

    }
```